# finding number of numbers which have prime number of factors

Tags: c, algorithm

The problem is to find the number of divisors of a number

ex-

```
for 10
```

ans=4

since 1,2,5,10 are the numbers which are  divisors

i.e. they are the factors

constraints are num<=10^6

I have implemented a code for the same but got TLE!!

here is my code

```
int isprime[MAX];

void seive()
{

    int i,
    j;

    isprime[0] = isprime[1] = 1;

    for (i = 4; i < MAX; i += 2) 
        isprime[i] = 1;

    for (i = 3; i * i < MAX; i += 2) {
        if (!isprime[i]) {
            for (j = i * i; j < MAX; j += 2 * i) 
                isprime[j] = 1;

        }

    }

}
int main()
{

    seive();

    int t;

    long long num;

    scanf("%d", & t);

    while (t--) {

        scanf("%lld", & num);



            cnt = 0;

            for (j = 1; j * j <= num; j++) {
                if (num % j == 0) {
                    cnt++;

                    if (num / j != j) 
                        cnt++;

                }





        printf("%lld\n", cnt);

    }

    return 0;

}
```

Can somebody help me to optimize it?

I have also searched about it but didnot getting any sucess.

So Please help guys.

Comment: nicely coded. :O someone format it

Comment: Please properly indent your code, so we can read it.

Comment: So on the plus side after a lot of googling I now know what "TLE" is -- Time Limit Exceeded.

Comment: dont ask questions directly from running contest http://www.codechef.com/NOV13/problems/PRETNUM

Comment: It is a question from November long contest conducted by CodeChef. Directly asking the question from running contest violates CodeChef's code of conduct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try computing this mathematically (I'm not sure this will be faster/easier).  Basically, given the prime factorization of a number, you should be able to calculate the number of divisors without too much trouble.

If you have an input `x` decompose into something like

```
x = p1^a1 * p2^a2 * ... pn^an
```

Then the number of divisors should be

```
prod(ai + 1) for i in 1 to n
```

I would then look at finding the smallest prime < sqrt(x), dividing that out until you're left with just a prime.  A sieve might still be useful and I don't know what kind of input you would be getting.

Now consider what the above statement says: the number of divisors in the product of the powers of the prime factorization (plus 1).  Thus, if you only every care if the result is prime, then you should only ever consider numbers which are prime, or powers of primes.  And within that, you then only need to consider powers such that a1 + 1 is prime.

That should significantly cut down your search space.

Comment: Yeah, I forgot to include the fact that you only care about numbers with prime divisors.  Then you only care about primes and powers of primes.

Answer (score 3):

If the prime factorization of a number is:

```
x = p1^e1 * p2^e2 * ... * pk^ek
```

Then the number of divisors is:

```
(e1 + 1)*(e2 + 1)* ... *(ek + 1)
```

For this to be prime, you need all `ei` to be 0, except one, which needs to be a prime - 1.

This is only true for primes and powers of primes. So you need to find how many powers of primes are in `[l, r]`. For example, `2^6` has `(6 + 1) = 7` prime factors.

Now you just need to sieve enough primes fast enough. You only need to sieve those in `[l, r]`, so an interval of size max `10^6`.

To sieve directly in this interval, remove multiples of 2 directly from `[l, r]`, and same for the rest. You can sieve primes up to `10^6` and use those to do the interval sieving later.

You can do the necessary counting while you're sieving as well.

Comment: @RaunakTalwar - you have to check if the exponents of primes + 1 are primes too. `3 + 1` is not prime. The exponents will be very small (`2^64` already far exceeds `10^12`), so this is an easy and fast check.